# Mutexes inside interrupt service routine

Tags: mutex, interrupt

In linux, why can't we have a mutex inside an isr() routine for protecting a shared resource ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a lock operation on a mutex can sleep and it's illegal to sleep in an ISR. Use a spinlock instead.